# Issue with adding fields of multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have three tables with same structure.

**table1**

```
id  | email         | count    
1   | test1@abc.com | 5    
2   | test2@abc.com | 5
3   | test3@abc.com | 5
```

**table2**

```
id  | email         | count    
1   | test1@abc.com | 50    
2   | test1@abc.com | 50    
3   | test3@abc.com | 50
```

**table3**

```
id  | email         | count    
1   | test1@abc.com | 40    
2   | test1@abc.com | 45    
3   | test1@abc.com | 50
```

Now what i want is for table1, for first record "test1@abc.com", I need sum of "count" field of next two tables. So i used below query

```
SELECT (IFNULL(sum(distinct(table2.count)), 0) +     
IFNULL(sum(distinct(table3.count)), 0)) as total 
FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.email = table2.email 
LEFT JOIN table3 ON table1.email = table3.email 
WHERE table1.email = 'test1@abc.com'
```

This query gives me below record:

`185`

But the result should be as below:

`235`

This is because i have used distinct when adding field. But if i don't use distinct, it gives me `285`.

Please help. What should i do?

Comment: Is [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6ddb9/19) what you meant to do?

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is because, first, you're using `LEFT JOIN` (no sense with summation since NULL-records will provide nothing), second, that's how `JOIN` works. Illustrate with query:

```
SELECT
  t1.id AS id_1,
  t1.email AS email_1,
  t1.count AS count_1,
  t2.id AS id_2,
  t2.email AS email_2,
  t2.count AS count_2,
  t3.id AS id_3,
  t3.email AS email_3,
  t3.count AS count_3
FROM
  table1 AS t1
    INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.email=t2.email
    INNER JOIN table3 AS t3 ON t1.email=t3.email
WHERE
  t1.email='test1@abc.com'
```

(fiddle is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6ddb9/5)). As you can see, you'll get repeated id's from second and third tables - and - yes, that's because there are multiple rows for joining condition.

To resolve your issue you may add distinction by id into join (and later filtering that with variables or like that), but I would not recommend it. `JOIN` is simply not the thing for your issue. Use `UNION`, like:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(`count`) AS s
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      table2.count
    FROM
      table2
    WHERE
      email='test1@abc.com'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      table3.count
    FROM
      table3
    WHERE
      email='test1@abc.com'
  ) AS u
```

(see the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6ddb9/6))